# Slide show issue

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slideshow

I'm using novus wordpress theme. I cant add a slide show to my web site. It has two sliders. They are camera slider and onebyone slider.I was uploaded images using theme options but they are not displaying in my home page. onebyone slider's images are displaying but not animating.
camera slider is completely not working.  Please help me. here is my homepage slider code ,

```
 <?php
global $slider_type, $ns_options_frnt;?>
        <?php if (sizeof($ns_options_frnt['css_addSlide_field'])>0){?>
        <?php

            //nivo, jfancytile, c1, c3, no_slider
            if(true)
            {
        ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        <?php if($ns_options_frnt['ns_select_slider'] == 'default'){ ?>
            jQuery(function(jQuery){
                if (jQuery('div').is('#header-slider')){
                    jQuery('#header-slider').camera({
                        height: 'auto',
                        navigation: false,
                        navigationHover: false,
                    loader: 'none',
                    pagination: false,
                    thumbnails: true,
                    mobileAutoAdvance: true,
                    autoAdvance: <?php echo $ns_options_frnt['front_Auto'] == 'enable' ? 'true' :'false'?>,
                    time: <?php echo ($ns_options_frnt['front_AutoSpeed'] ? $ns_options_frnt['front_AutoSpeed'] :7000)?>,
                    fx: "<?php echo $ns_options_frnt['front_fx'] ? $ns_options_frnt['front_fx'] :'simpleFade, curtainSliceLeft, curtainSliceRight, scrollBottom, scrollTop'?>",
                        Cols:  "<?php echo $ns_options_frnt['front_Cols'] ? $ns_options_frnt['front_Cols'] :4?>",
                        Rows:  "<?php echo $ns_options_frnt['front_Rows'] ? $ns_options_frnt['front_Rows'] :1?>",
                        slicedCols:  "<?php echo $ns_options_frnt['front_slicedCols'] ? $ns_options_frnt['front_slicedCols'] :4?>",
                        slicedRows: "<?php echo $ns_options_frnt['front_slicedRows'] ? $ns_options_frnt['front_slicedRows'] :1?>",
                        transPeriod: <?php echo $ns_options_frnt['front_box_speed'] ? $ns_options_frnt['front_box_speed'] :2500?>                       




/*




                        */
                    });
                }
            });
        <?php }elseif($ns_options_frnt['ns_select_slider'] == 'onebyone'){ ?>
            jQuery(document).ready(function() { 

   jQuery('#banner').oneByOne({
        className: 'oneByOne1',              
        /* Please provide the width and height in the responsive 
        version, for the slider will keep the ratio when resize 
        depends on these size. */
        width: 1000,
        height: 420,
        easeType: 'random',
        slideShow: true,
        responsive: true,
        minWidth: 480,
                    delay: <?php echo $ns_options_frnt['frontOneByOne_AutoSpeed'] ? $ns_options_frnt['frontOneByOne_AutoSpeed'] :'300'?>,
        tolerance: <?php echo $ns_options_frnt['frontOneByOne_Tolerance'] ? $ns_options_frnt['frontOneByOne_Tolerance'] :'0.25'?>,                          
        slideShowDelay: <?php echo $ns_options_frnt['frontOneByOne_box_speed'] ? $ns_options_frnt['frontOneByOne_box_speed'] :'2000'?>
    });
```

/*

Comment: is that showing any error in console?

Comment: Can you post the generated html, also have you checked your browsers console log for specific error messages?

Comment: Did you fine any solution for  your issue , If yes Then kindly share it.